# Assigning a pointer to a struct to a variable

Tags: c, pointers, struct, variable-assignment, lvalue

I'm having trouble using the pointer returned by the make_employee function out in the main program.

//    I have the following code in a separate .c file:

```
struct Employee;

struct Employee* make_employee(char* name, int birth_year, int start_year){
  struct Employee* new = (struct Employee*)malloc(sizeof(struct Employee));
  strcpy(new->name, name);
  new->birth_year = birth_year;
  new->start_year = start_year;
  return new;
}


//In the main program:

int main()
{
  char test_name[] = "Fred";
  int test_birth = 1989;
  int test_start = 2007;

  Employee Fred;

  make_employee(test_name, test_birth, test_start) = &Fred;     <-- throws invalid lvalue error

  return 0
}
```

Comment: The left side of that assignment statement is.... *not* an lvalue. Or was that not clear in the error message.

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign something to a non-lvalue. Thus the name (l-value, left-side value, can appear on the **left** side of an assignment expression).

Is *this* what you're trying to do??

```
int main()
{
  char test_name[] = "Fred";
  int test_birth = 1989;
  int test_start = 2007;

  struct Employee *fred = make_employee(test_name, test_birth, test_start)

  // use fred....

  free(fred);

  return 0
}
```

Note: don't cast `malloc()` in C. Make sure `stdlib.h` is included in your source file, and let the compiler warn you if you forgot to do so. If you receive a warning stating to the effect "implicit declaration of `malloc` returning `int`"  etc, it means you forgot to include `stdlib.h`, and you should do so.

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm trying to do. I'm getting a warning (initialization from incompatible pointer type) on this line:

struct Employee *fred = make_employee(test_name, test_birth, test_start);

Comment: Try `struct Employee* make_employee(const char* name, int birth_year, int start_year)` for your function declaration. Also, make *sure* it is either prototyped or declared *above* `main()` in the same source file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check your make_employee function . The reason i say so is in the code that you posted you use the following line

```
struct Employee* new = (struct Employee*)malloc(sizeof(struct Employee));
```

new is a keyword in C++ and should have thrown you compilation errors right away if you had used a C++ complier . It is not good to make use of keywords as variable names .

ALso check the return value from the function .

Assuming that you have declared your structure correctly this should work well

```
struct Employee* make_employee(char* name, int birth_year, int start_year){
  struct Employee *ptr = (struct Employee*)malloc(sizeof(struct Employee));
  strcpy(ptr->name, name);
  ptr->birth_year = birth_year;
  ptr->start_year = start_year;
  return ptr;
}


//In the main program:

int main()
{
  char test_name[] = "Fred";
  int test_birth = 1989;
  int test_start = 2007;

  Employee *Fred = make_employee(test_name, test_birth, test_start) ;   

  printf("Printing the data contents");
  printf("\n Name : %s",Fred->name);
  printf("\n Birth : %d",Fred->birth_year);
  printf("\n Start :%d",Fred->start_year);
  free(Fred);
  return 0;
}
```